# How to find the exact points that an edge connects in jgraphx?

Tags: jgraphx

For an edge in jgraphx which has its geometry set to relative, there are no points provided as they are derived from the source and target for the edge.

However, the points found there are the top left corner of the objects: what I would like to know is if there is a way to get the exact points in which the edge connects to the source and target vertex rather than just the position or center point of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Try `graph.getView().getPerimeterPoint(mxCellState, mxPoint...)`

Provide as cell state your local cell (`mxGraphView.getState(myLocalCell)`) and as point the distant center point of your other cell linked by the edge (you may compute it from its geometry X, Y, Width and Height).

Answer (score 0):

An jGraphx can be exported to `svg` format. Maybe the `drawCell()` in the `com.mxgraph.canvas.mxSvgCanvas` can help you out. It is the case when `shape.equals(mxConstants.SHAPE_LINE)` and how the `M` and `L` commands are being calculated.